# Difference in iOS allocation between XCode and instruments

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, xcode7, instruments

We have an iOS application that we were optimizing the memory allocations.I checked the allocation from XCode debugger and instrument allocation tool,to my surprise they both showed different readings. Can anybody explain what I am doing wrong. I have attached the screenshots of my instruments tool.The high point is 97.17 MB in instruments but in Xcode it's 74 MB!!!

Added Info - The application runs in debug mode both in Xcode and Instruments.
Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: More information required.  Are they the same configuration (Release/Debug)?

Comment: @GhostCode The difference in memory usage is not a sign of anything wrong in your code. The memory usage that Xcode and Instruments report are not going to match. BTW, your app is only using 8 MB of heap allocations. The heap allocations is a more accurate measure of your app's actual memory usage.